# SEDE: Invalid column name

Tags: support, data-explorer, accepted-answer

I'm trying a SEDE query to known the questions that has an accepted answer and with big difference of votes between the accepted answer as "best" answer.

My try of query is:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    q.Title,
    (select max(m.Score) from Posts m where m.ParentId = q.Id ) as Maximum,
    a.Score as Accepted

FROM
    Posts q
  INNER JOIN
    Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id

WHERE
    q.PostTypeId = 1

order by Maximum-Accepted desc
```

however, following error appears:

> Invalid column name 'Maximum'. Invalid column name 'Accepted'.

Looking for examples, I see similar ones, it seems the query is near than ok, but I do not see where is the error.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Your SQL is wrong, this question is off topic here. For valid SQL for what you need, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883753/order-sql-query-by-2-columns-and-do-mathematical-operations-first\

Comment: @ShadowWizard: it is obvious my sql is wrong, an error appears when I execute it.  Moreover, what you call "valid SQL for what you need" is an example of something very unrelated (no inner select, ...), see at received answer. Finally, this is a query for stack exchange data using SEDE, SQL has lot of variants, I think it is on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay DRY add an extra query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10
       Title
     , Maximum
     , Accepted
FROM
(
  SELECT
    q.Title,
    (select max(m.Score) from Posts m where m.ParentId = q.Id ) as [Maximum],
    a.Score as [Accepted]
  FROM
      Posts q
    INNER JOIN
      Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
  WHERE
     q.PostTypeId = 1
) as data

ORDER BY ([Maximum]-[Accepted]) DESC
```

See it live [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/774971).

Based on the comments I decided to look at the queryplans for both queries:

This is the one for my query:

[image: query plan for my query]

And here is the one from [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel)

[image: glorfindel]

It looks like my query does one index scan less and due to that needs one hash match less. Who could have predicted that. SQL Server awesomeness confirmed ...

After I revisited this the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/775504?opt.withExecutionPlan=true#executionPlan) only does two clustered_index_scan's so that should perform even slightly better.

Comment: I was always afraid that such queries would blow up, because the inner query has so many results, but SQL Server is smarter than I thought.

Comment: @Glorfindel well, it looks like we can trust SQL Server. I honestly wouldn't have predicted that outcome ....

Comment: Thabks for the answer. Why enclose some names in brackets?

Comment: Just in case they turned out to be a reserved word @pasabaporaqui

Answer (score 1):

What helps is just writing out the definitions of the columns:

```sql
order by (select max(m.Score) from Posts m where m.ParentId = q.Id ) - a.Score desc
```

[This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/774960/order-by-fix) is the resulting query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. No way to use "as" ? Rewrite the inner query seems something to skip.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm not a SQL wizard. Like Shadow Wizard says, this is more of an (advanced) SQL question than a SEDE question.